# Tufte tables: convert quartile plots into standard error plots hacking qTable function from NMOF package

Tags: r, latex, data-visualization, standard-error, tufte

If you remember there is a nice version of table conceived by Tufte that include small quartile plots running next to the corresponding data rows:

[image]

There is an implementation of such solution in R using [package NMOF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMOF/index.html) and function `qTable`, which basically creates the table shown above and outputs it as a LaTeX code:

```
require(NMOF)
x <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 2)
y <- rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 2)
z <- rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.5)
X <- cbind(x, y, z)
qTable(X,filename="res.tex")#this will save qTable in tex format in current dir
```

This method of visualization seem to be especially useful if you have a small amount of information to present, and you don't want to waste a space for the full graph. But I would like to hack `qTable` a bit. Instead of displaying quantile plots, I would prefer to display standard errors of the mean. I am not great in hacking such functions, and I used brute force to do it. I replaced the line from the `qTable` function which computes quantiles:

```
A <- apply(X, 2L, quantile, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))
```

with something very brutal, that computes standard errors:

```
require(psych)#got 'SE' function to compute columns standard deviation     
M = colMeans(X)#column means
SE = SD(X)/sqrt(nrow(X))#standard error
SELo = M-SE#lower bound
SEHi = M+SE#upper bound
A = t(data.frame(SELo,M,SEHi))#combines it together
```

I know, I know it's possibly unsustainable approach, but it actually works to some extend - it plots standard errors but keeps this gap in the plot:

[image]

and I would like this gap to disappear.

[Here is a qTable function with modification discussed above](https://gist.github.com/3078746).

Comment: interesting idea - I think what you need to tweak is the Latex code that does the drawing, that is where the start and end points of those lines are specified, not in the R code.

Comment: @atiretoo: Yes, that's probably the case, but I still didn't figure out how to hack the LaTeX part.

Comment: When you say you'd like the gap to disappear, do you mean that you want something that looks like the plot for 'neutral' in your first included figure?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: Yes, pretty much like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the gaps, you can insert these two lines:

```
B[2, ] <- B[3, ]
B[4, ] <- B[3, ]
```

right before the `for` loop that starts with

```
for (cc in 1L:dim(X)[2L]) {...
```

Why does it work? Reading the graph from left to right, the five rows of `B` correspond to where

```
1) the left segments start
2) the left segments ends
3) the dots are
4) the right segments start
5) the right segments end
```

so by forcing `B[2, ]` and `B[4, ]` to `B[3, ]` you are effectively getting rid of the gaps.

Comment: Yep, that works, easy and nice fix, and I know where it comes from now. Cheers mate.